# Execute two Zenity dialogs side by side

Tags: bash, user-interface, dialog, zenity

I want to write a script in bash using zenity for UI. My idea is to have 2 diaglos open side by side: one to interact with user and second to display results. Is it possible to set positions of these dialogs to avoid dialogs overlapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine 2 scripts using zenity. The main for the output and the child for the UI input.